# Firefox complains about java plugin security even with the latest version

Tags: windows, firefox, windows-vista, java

When I go to any web page that uses java, for example www.java.com -> Do I have Java? , it complains that the java version installed has security flaws. However I have the latest version (7 u 45) and I have checked on java.com and I don't have any old versions installed.  Is this a firefox bug and is there any way round it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox has blocked Java plugins due to alleged security issues.  This isn't related to any particular version of Java.
There is a way round it described on the Mozilla website:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-to-enable-java-if-its-been-blocked

Comment: It has blocked all java plugins?! I had no idea.